# Book in which citizens earned money for playing video games

Tags: story-identification, games

Does anyone know the name of this book? I don't remember the title but I remember some details about it.

- it was a world where you played video games to earn money ;
- there were guilds and it was told from different perspectives ;
- in the end, one of the female characters sacrifices her self to save her guild members.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Does this movie prompt any memories> "Avalon (2001 film)" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalon_(2001_film).

Comment: Do you remember anything about the Author, any particular quotes or events? What would also be useful is the nature of the video game they're playing. Was it futuristic? Medieval? Some kind of Action-RPG, FPS, etc...

Comment: Can you say for sure it's not Ready Player One by Ernest Cline? I don't think there are different perspectives in it, though.